# Dict from list of dicts

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list of dicts.

```
dictList = [
  {'name': 'some name'},
  {'name': 'some other name'},
  {'age': 'some age'},
  {'last_name': 'some last name'}
]
```

In that list of dicts each dict has one key and one value for that key, as shown above.

I need to create a dict that has the keys from all the dicts and each value for every key is a set with item values from the list of dicts. In the example, it'd be something like this:

```
expected_dict = {
    'name': ['some name', 'some other name'],
    'age': ['some age'],
    'last_name': ['some last name']
}
```

How can I do this in Python?

Comment: @jpp now edited.

Comment: What have you tried that isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the builtin [`setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) function.

```
dictList = [
  {'name': 'some name'},
  {'name': 'some other name'},
  {'age': 'some age'},
  {'last_name': 'some last name'}
]

expected_dict = {}

for dictionary in dictList:
    for key, val in dictionary.items():
        expected_dict.setdefault(key, []).append(val)

print(expected_dict)
```

Output:

```
{
    'name': ['some name', 'some other name'], 
    'age': ['some age'], 
    'last_name': ['some last name']
}
```

**Note:** Using `collections.defaultdict` (as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49037117/7832176)) is simpler and faster than using `dict.setdefault()`.

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples):

Working of `collections.defaultdict`:

> When each key is encountered for the first time, it is not already in the mapping; so an entry is automatically created using the `default_factory` function which returns an empty list. The `list.append()` operation then attaches the value to the new list. When keys are encountered again, the look-up proceeds normally (returning the list for that key) and the `list.append()` operation adds another value to the list. This technique is simpler and faster than an equivalent technique using `dict.setdefault()`.

Comment: Out of interest, is there a reason you prefer this method as opposed to the (equivalent) `collections.defaultdict`?

Comment: Tbh, I was not aware of `collections.defaultdict`. Thought using the builtin method is better. I'd like to know which method is better.

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples), `defaultdict is simpler and faster than an equivalent technique using dict.setdefault()`. Question answered. I'll keep my answer instead of deleting it as an alternative method.

Answer (score 2):

`collections.defaultdict` is one way:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

dictList = [
  {'name': 'some name'},
  {'name': 'some other name'},
  {'age': 'some age'},
  {'last_name': 'some last name'}
]

for i in dictList:
    for k, v in i.items():
        d[k].append(v)

# defaultdict(list,
#             {'age': ['some age'],
#              'last_name': ['some last name'],
#              'name': ['some name', 'some other name']})
```

Comment: are the values of the dict, sets?

Answer (score 1):

```
bigD = {}
for element in dictList:
    for key in element:
        if key in bigD:
            bigD[key].append(element[key])
        else:
            bigD[key] = element[key]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import import itertools
dictList = [
    {'name': 'some name'},
    {'name': 'some other name'},
    {'age': 'some age'},
    {'last_name': 'some last name'}
]
new_list = {a:[c for [[_, c]] in b] for a, b in itertools.groupby(map(lambda x:x.items(), dictList), key=lambda x:x[0][0])}
```

Output:

```
{'age': ['some age'], 'last_name': ['some last name'], 'name': ['some name', 'some other name']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simply.

```
dict = {} 
list = [1,2,3]
dict['numbs'] = list
print(dict)
```

Output : 
`{'numbs': [1, 2, 3]}`